# Extract Data from Image to Text in angular

Tags: angular, tesseract, tesseract.js

I want to extract the data from image using Tesseract.js in my angular project.

Can anybody given an example for how to do the extraction of data from image

Answer (score 1):

You can try out below logic, which was implemented part of poc:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { createWorker } from 'tesseract.js';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'poc for ocr';
  ocrResult = 'Loading the library...';

  constructor() {
    this.doOCR();
  }

  async doOCR() {
    const worker = createWorker({
      logger: m => console.log(m),
    });
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
    await worker.initialize('eng');
    const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize('<your image>');
    this.ocrResult = text;
    console.log(text);
    await worker.terminate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check project github repository for [documentation](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractjs) and [examples](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/examples.md)

```
import { TesseractWorker } from 'tesseract.js';
const worker = new TesseractWorker();

worker.recognize(myImage)
  .progress(progress => {
    console.log('progress', progress);
  }).then(result => {
    console.log('result', result);
  });
```

Comment: or do you have problems how to use that code in angular? Then maybe check [angular + webworkers](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker)

Comment: while adding import { TesseractWorker } from 'tesseract.js';
Module '"../../../node_modules/@types/tesseract.js"' has no exported member 'TesseractWorker' error is coming.Can you help me to solve this? @Xesenix

Comment: From what I see on fast lookup it should work I need to create my own example to check what can be the issue will do that after returning home in few hours